# Using "this" class context inside promise resolver

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Is it possible to pass the current context (`this`) into a Promise resolver? It seems to erase within the resolver.

Example:

```
class A {
  constructor(someObject) {
    this.someObject = someObject;
  }

  foo() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.someObject.doAsyncRequest(arg, function(val) { resolve(val); });
    });
  }
}
```

EDIT:

The error will be:
"cannot read someObject of undefined"

EDIT2:
Apologies, this actually works. I had a bug in webpack that was inserting some random garbage into the file before serving it.

Comment: That works for me - how do you call `foo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a more stripped down version and what you have works just fine:

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.a = "hello";
  }
  
  foo() {
     return new Promise(resolve => resolve(this.a));
  }
}

const a = new A();
a.foo().then(a => console.log(a));
```

Since you are using an arrow function inside of the `Promise`, the `this` context is maintained.

Now, if you use a normal function, you do lose `this` as it will become undefined (check the browser console, as it throws an error SO doesn't show):

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.a = "hello";
  }
  
  foo() {
     return new Promise(function(resolve) { resolve(this.a) });
  }
}

const a = new A();
a.foo().then(a => console.log(a));
```

If you want to maintain the context with that, you'll need to bind it:

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.a = "hello";
  }
  
  foo() {
     return new Promise((function(resolve) { resolve(this.a) }).bind(this));
  }
}

const a = new A();
a.foo().then(a => console.log(a));
```

If you are using `foo()` as a callback, that can also lose context (again, check browser console since it throws an error):

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.a = "hello";
  }
  
  foo() {
     return new Promise(resolve => resolve(this.a));
  }
}

const a = new A();
const callback = a.foo;

callback().then(a => console.log(a));
```

To fix that, bind it before you use it as a callback:

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.a = "hello";
  }
  
  foo() {
     return new Promise(resolve => resolve(this.a));
  }
}

const a = new A();
const callback = a.foo.bind(a);
callback().then(a => console.log(a));
```

Comment: Since when is _"...what you have **works just fine**"_ an answer? O.o

Comment: "what you have [in your specific example you've provided] works just fine, but here are things that might be happening in your real code" is a decent answer I believe...

Comment: that last addiction about `A.foo.bind(A)` is probably OP's problem. But we cannot be sure until he provides us a way to replicate his problem. So, a guess should be fine.

Comment: I think I covered just about all of the possibilities. One way or another, there isn't proper binding going on.

Comment: @Federkun TO uses an arrow function, hence `.bind()` won't change `this`

Comment: Actually, it will matter for the outer one, even with an arrow function in the promise, since the this from outside the arrow function will be lost. I've updated my code to show an example of that as well.

Comment: @Andreas, it will. `a.foo.apply(document).then(a => document.write(a));`